# How to push local Git modifications to Gitlab repository without direct SSH or HTTPs access through an intermediate server?

Tags: git, gitlab, guacamole

For some reasons I don't have direct access to my Gitlab instance (no direct SSH, HTTPs nor VPN access). I can only access a virtual Desktop running within a Web Browser (Apache Guacamole in this case) from my laptop. I can copy paste text content or upload files to a remote RDP host server which has SSH/HTTPs access to Gitlab server.

How could I push my local commits to Gitlab server using this intermediate RDP Server? What would be the steps to push all my local commits?

1. Zip my local repository containing ".git" subdirectory
2. Upload to remote server / Virtual Desktop through Web browser
3. Unzip my local repository archive on remote RDP host server
4. Configure Tortoise Git
5. Push to Gitlab server (reachable from the remote remote RDP host server) from remote RDP host server

Is it feasable following above steps or are there additionnal limitations or possible issues that I should be aware of?